# rviz integration with different frames and sensors

Tags: navigation, rviz, laser, a200, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Heyy People,

I am a recent user of ROS and rviz. I am currently using Husky A200 for my project activities and I found rviz to be particularly interesting.

I displayed my Hokoyu LIDAR output on rviz. However, there was still an error shown on the .Global parameters section saying the frame /laser does not exist. This happens further, to any new frame that I wish to see but that does not exist in the drop-down list.

How should I modify rviz so that these frames are visible in the dropdown list or work with no errors? Further, I am wanting to solve this issue in the context of localization and mapping so that I see in real-time the map development using rviz.

My tf frames only consists of the Camera frames from my Kinect as follows:
/camera_link

/camera_rgb_frame ,
/camera_depth_frame

/camera_rgb_optical_frame ,
/camera_depth_optical_frame

Any help in this regards would be appreciated.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31257/rviz-integration-with-different-frames-and-sensors/) by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 612 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-04-04**:
What does your tf tree look like? (what frames exist?) If you're not sure, you can use "rosrun tf view_frames" to display the full tf tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For each sensor measurement you have, there must be a frame associated to it. And the frames should be connected on a tree. I am guessing that you are missing a link in that tree, to reference your laser frame to the /map or /world frame, for example.

You can create static frame transformations in a launch file, if that is the case:

[ROS static transform](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher)

regards

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1